# How do I create a stacked bar chart (or better, line plot) in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, stacked-chart

I am trying to turn a normal line plot or bar chart into a stacked bar plot using a grouping variable.  When I try to add a grouping variable in the "Group Rows" section and then redraw the plot it, I cannot figure out how to split out the data in the visualization.  Can someone help?  I know the standard approach here is to give a reproducible example, but I don't know how I would do that in SalesForce.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you have included the grouping variable in the reporting table, click on 'Run' and go to the visualization.

Click on the 'Gear' icon in the upper right corner of the visualization, and under X-axis click on " + Group" and it will provide you the option to select your grouping variable from there.